# remove element attribute value in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("#options").find("a").click(function() {
    var sendbuttonval = $(this).attr('id');
    document.querySelector('#save_option').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var date = document.querySelector('.date').value;
        var time = document.querySelector('.time').value;

        if (sendbuttonval=='option_1') {
            newDate = new Date(date + 'T' + time);
            var m = newDate.getTime() + newDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            var c = Date.now();
            var t = m - c;

            setTimeout(function() {
                  alert('Vaccine Reminder');
            }, t);

            console.log(newDate);
            console.log(m);
        } else if (sendbuttonval == 'option_2') {
            alert('success');
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container" id="vaccines">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>Birth</h3>
            <br><br>
            <?php
                $date = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM vaccination_date WHERE calendar='Birth'");
                while ($row = $date->fetch()) {?>
                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" id="<?php echo $row['vaccine']?>" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['vaccine']?></a>
        <div id="display_date"></div>
                    <br>
            <?php } ?>
    <h3>Week 6</h3>
          <?php
      $date1 = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM vaccination_date WHERE calendar='Week 6'");
      while ($row1 = $date1->fetch()) {?>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" id="<?php echo $row1['vaccine']?>" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row1['vaccine']?></a>
        <br>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="options">
            <?php
                $date = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM options");
                while ($row = $date->fetch()) {?>
                       <a href="#myModal1" role="button" id="option_<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['option_name']?></a>
                    <br>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

×

```
       <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <section class="demo">
            <p>Remind at: &nbsp;
            <input class="date" id="date" type="date">
            <input class="time" id="time" type="time">
            <input type="hidden" id="u_id" name="u_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['open'];?>">
              <button id="save_option">Submit</button>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following `if` statement after trying to alert the attribute. For example the attribute value is `option_1` it will display the `alert('Vaccine Reminder');`

After clicking `option_2` it will display `alert('Success')` and `alert('Vaccine Reminder');` and that's what not suppose to happen, it should only display `Success`.

I think the problem here is the elements attribute value still remains thats why it's messing up with the `if` statement, is there any way to like clear the value of the element's attribute

Comment: No, the problem is much more likely that you are adding event handlers multiple times. Each time your outer handler (on links within the `#options` element) runs, it adds a new click handler to `#save_option`. And that explains why you are getting two alerts (or more, if you keep on clicking and therefor adding event handlers) – because otherwise, that would be impossible, if the code was executed only once, because the if and else branch are never _both_ stepped into at the same time.

Comment: If you can paste the corresponding html code, it'll be more helpful

Comment: how can i get the var sendvaccineval = $(this).attr('id'); value then? cuz im gonna use it inside $("#options").find("a").click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you have a click-listener inside another click-listener. Each time you click the first listenener, another click event will be created. Either try to move the second listener outside the first or remove the second listener before attaching it again. Best case would be to move the second listener outside. You could create a variable outside both listener for checking if the code in your second listener should be performed. For example:

`var firstClickSet = false;
$("#options").find("a").click(function() { firstClickSet = true; }
document.querySelector('#save_option').addEventListener('click', function() { if(firstSetClick) { //your code };`

By the way, why are you using jquery for the first listener and native js for the second one?

Comment: how can i get the var sendvaccineval = $(this).attr('id'); value then? cuz im gonna use it inside $("#options").find("a").click(function() {

Comment: make it the same way as firstClickSet. Declare the variable outside of both event listener, add the value in the first listener (the options-click) and use this variable inside the second listner ("save options").